# Issues Using Wildcard in Batch-script to Copy a Variable File Name

Tags: batch-file, copy, wildcard

**My Process:**

For version control, all my files are named with the format "fileName_v#.#"

I keep a folder called 'Live Environment', and as a new version is rolled out, the current file (ex. fileName_v1.0) is removed from 'Live Environment' folder, and the new version (ex. fileName_v2.0) is moved into 'Live Environment'.

My batch script is used to keep all users on the most current version.  It works perfect, except with every version I need to go back and update the hard-coded file name in my script to the new file name.

*I would like to use a wildcard to search this folder for whatever file is in the 'Live Environment' folder, and then perform the copy function.*

**Current Code:**

```
::Sets the default install location as the user's desktop
set "DestinationFolder=%userprofile%\desktop"

::Copies and saves file to the user's Desktop
copy /-y "\\myUNCPath\Live Environment\fileName_v*.accdb" "%DestinationFolder%\copiedFile.accdb"
```

**My Issue:**

I've hardcoded the "fileName_v#.#.accdb" in for each version so far, and the code executes perfectly.  The second I remove the hardcoded file version and add the "*" wildcard, the code errors.  The copy function still runs, but simply creates an empty .accdb file on the users desktop, which when used gives the error:

> "Unrecognized database format"

At this point I'm overthinking this and making it harder than it needs to be.  A set of fresh eyes on the issue would be helpful.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try with `copy /-Y /B`; the `copy` command treats your source as multiple source files, because wildcards are used, and tries to concatenate them; even if only one file matches, `copy` might handle the source file as a text file, so I guess line-break codes are converted and so the binary image might be modified...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@aschipfl - that worked! Thanks for the comment.

Simply adding "/b" to the copy line fixed the issue.

```
copy /-y /b
```

(For more details see the aschipfl's comment posted below the question).